# Is it acceptable to use "whose" when referring to an object?

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

*Whose* is used for people (e.g. "Whose that girl?"), but is it acceptable to use *whose* for objects too?
Is there another word I should use for objects?

To make the question clearer, when I ask "Whose that car?" I am expecting an answer similar to "It's *X*'s car." where *X* refers to a person. I could say "a man whose opinion I respect." and *whose opinion* would refer to the opinion of a person.
Could I say "the desk **whose** drawer was broken by my brother"? Should I replace *whose* with another word?

Comment: Bad example for usage of "whose". It should have been "Who is that girl?". Valid example for "whose" could be "A girl *whose* necklace was stolen".

Comment: Similar question at ELU: Can “whose” refer to an inanimate object?  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/can-whose-refer-to-an-inanimate-object

Comment: Please fix up the example in your question so that people don't keep on "answering" to correct the mistake in your "example" rather than answering the actual question which is "whether *whose* can be used with objects"!

Comment: I cannot remove the example I used, or the answer already given would not have anymore sense. (Somebody could wonder why two answers are about _whose_ versus _who's_ when the question is only about _whose_?) The two answers give a relevant information (don't confuse _whose_ with _who's_) even if the question was not limited to _whose_ used in that specific sentence.

Comment: You can't leave a mistake in a question intentionally just because answers have corrected your mistake rather than the "moderators". Since the crux of your question was whether *Whose* can be used with objects or not, it does not make much sense to leave "other non-core* mistakes in the stem of that question. If you change question, people who have already answered can also edit their respective answers appropriately.

Comment: On Stack Exchange sites, once answers are given, a question cannot be edited, if the edit invalidates the already given answers. Furthermore, the most up-voted answer explains the difference between _whose_ and _who's_, and it answers about using _whose_ in sentences like "Melbourne is a city whose public transport is good." which is the topic of the question. (Melbourne is a city, not the name of a person.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two uses of *whose*:

1. **Relative** *whose*, used in forming relative clauses.
2. **Interrogative** *whose*, used in asking a question.

The former can refer to inanimate objects, but the latter cannot.

---

Take a look at this sentence, in which **relative** *whose* refers to an inanimate object:

> Two of these were large marble jars ***whose*** manufacture must have represented an enormous amount of work since metal tools were unknown at that time. ([*source*](http://www.calstatela.edu/academic/anthro/americas.htm))

Here, **relative** *whose* refers back to the noun phrase *large marble jars*, an inanimate object.  This usage is fairly common and unremarkable.

However, **interrogative** *whose* does not have this ability.  If you wanted to ask which cars had engines that needed replacing, this sentence would be unacceptable:

> *Whose engines need replacing?

This is because **interrogative** *whose* cannot refer back to *cars*, an inanimate object.

---

Huddleston and Pullum use the labels *personal* and *non-personal* for this distinction.  In these terms, **interrogative** *whose* is personal, and **relative** *whose* can be either personal or non-personal.

---

In this answer, * marks a sentence as unacceptable.

Answer (score 9):

In your first example, you have mixed up *whose* with *who's*.  *Who's* is a contraction of *who is*; whereas *whose* is the possessive form of *who* or *which*, when used as an adjective.

> **Who's** that girl?

> **Whose** car is this?

> Melbourne is a city **whose** public transport is good.

> **Who's** that at the door?

As for your other example, it's perfectly valid to use *whose* when referring to an object. Saying something such as "the desk whose drawer was broken by my brother" is fine. The third example that I listed above is the usage of *whose* in just that manner.

Answer (score 1):

*Whose* isn't used when referring to people; *who's* is, which is the abbreviated form of "who is".

> Who's that girl?

*Whose* *is* used when identifying objects.

> Whose phone is that?

Comment: True, but when you ask "Whose phone is that?" you are not expecting the answer to be "It's the dog's phone."

Comment: @kiamlaluno That would depend... (But you wouldn't expect it)

Comment: A:  ***Whose daughter*** *are you seeing?* B: *The preacher's*

Answer (score -1):

> *Whose*: of whom/what.
>
> *Who's*: who is.

Since *who's* cannot refer to objects, but a person, we use *it's* (that's not the point, but still). *Whose* is a completely different word meaning *of whom/what*.

Comment: So, can you say "The desk whose drawer was broken by my brother"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: yes.

Comment: The possessive pronoun is spelled **its** there is no apostrophe, the meaning of it's = it is.